# How to populate a column using multiple conditionals across 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Im trying to populate a column with values based on two conditionals across two separate dataframes. So,

df1$day == df2$day & df1$hour == df2$hour then fill df1$X with df2$depth

I struggle because I am not asking it to populate it with a generic value (i.e. if x==y, then y2=1). I am trying to get it select values across multiple rows. A mock example:

```
df1                         df2
day   hour   X              day  hour   depth 
1      10    NA             1    10     50
1      11    NA             1    11     10
2      5     NA             1    3      100
5      9     NA             5    9      50
6      20    NA             7    17     80
7      17    NA             10    4     65
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, X := depth, on = .(day, hour)]
df1
#   day hour  X
#1:   1   10 50
#2:   1   11 10
#3:   2    5 NA
#4:   5    9 50
#5:   6   20 NA
#6:   7   17 80
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `match`

```
df1$X <- with(df1, df2$depth[match(paste(day, hour), paste(df2$day, df2$hour))])
```

#### data

```
df1<- data.frame(day = c(1, 1, 2, 5:7), hour = c(10:11, 5, 9, 20, 17),
         X = NA_integer_)
df2 <- data.frame(day = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 10), hour = c(10, 11, 3, 9, 
       17, 4), depth = c(50, 10, 100, 50, 80, 65))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can do a `left_join` and then `rename` the `depth` column as `X`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("day", "hour")) %>%
   select(-X) %>%
   rename(X = depth)

#  day hour  X
#1   1   10 50
#2   1   11 10
#3   2    5 NA
#4   5    9 50
#5   6   20 NA
#6   7   17 80
```

If the `X` column is not always `NA` you could use  `coalesce`.

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("day", "hour")) %>%
   mutate(X = coalesce(depth, X)) %>%
   select(names(df1))
```

---

Or in base R :

```
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)[-3]
```